# Defining an event for a windows forms custom control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, custom-controls

I'm working on an form custom control.the control is a MonthCalendar like Visual studio(C#) MonthCalendar control and I want to define an event for my control.
How can define a new event for this form custom control?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your event should not provide any additional info (Foo is name of your event):

```
public event EventHandler Foo;
```

And raise it this way:

```
protected virtual void OnFoo()
{
    if (Foo != null)
        Foo(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

If you need to pass some additional info to event handlers, then create custom arguments class by inheriting from `EvenArgs` class

```
public class FooEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public FooEventArgs(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

Declare event this way:

```
public event EventHandler<FooEventArgs> Foo;
```

And raise it this way:

```
protected virtual void OnFoo(string message)
{
   if (Foo != null)
       Foo(this, new FooEventArgs(message));
}
```

Its good practice to create protected methods for raising events by descendants of class where event is declared. Also good practice to use event naming convention:

- add suffix `-ing` to event name for events which raised before
  something happened (often you could cancel such events) (e.g. Validating)
- add suffix `-ed` to event name for events which raised after something happened (e.g. Clicked)

As Thorsten stated, good practice to create `virtual` methods for raising events. Its not only allows to raise events from descendants, but also disable event raising, or adding some behavior prior/after event raising.

Comment: In addition, it is good practise to raise the event through a `protected virtual void` method named `OnXXX` where `XXX` is the name of your event. In the sample above: `protected virtual void OnFoo(...)`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar exactly! my bad - forgot `virtual` keyword in examples

Answer (score 0):

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> YourEvent;
```